# Behavioral data on contrast sensitivity

Tags: hypothesis-testing, repeated-measures

I have done behavioral experiments,and have no clue even how to start making statistics on the data.

Here is the description of the experiment:
Mice are subjected to an experimental task where they have to distinguish stripe patterns of various contrasts and width. It is known that at a certain spatial frequency (stripe width) the contrast sensitivity is best, and with wider or narrower stripes the sensitivity becomes worse (see e.g. [here](http://www.ndt-ed.org/EducationResources/CommunityCollege/PenetrantTest/Introduction/contrastsensitivity.htm))

So: For every mouse (n=7) we tested at a **given stripe width** and determined the contrast at which it was just able to see the stripes. That is,we get 7 data points per width. We did this for 3 widths: the "optimal" width, and a wider and a narrower width. As result, we get some V-shaped curve (connecting the means for each stripe width).
Next, we tested at a **given contrast** (relatively high contrast, i.e. stripes can be seen well) and checked how narrow the stripes can be made. Again, we get 1 data point for each mouse. We did this for 2 different contrasts.

Taken together, for each mouse we have 5 data points in the form {stripe_width,contrast}, where 3 times the width was fixed, and contrast may vary from mouse to mouse, and 2 times the contrast was fixed, and the width may vary from mouse to mouse.

Now comes the tricky part: These mice are known to become worse as they become older. So we repeated the same test, with the same mice, 3 times within a couple of weeks. In the plot below, black is the original measurement, red after 1 week, green after 2 weeks.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I am now looking for a statistical test to show that they really see worse with age (they do - I want to quantify it). Some even become blind, so that I do not have numerical values for {stripe_width,contrast}, but one could imagine (maybe) that one can set the needed contrast to Infinity (or some other high value compared to the real data) for the experimental tests where one keeps the widths fixed. The blind ones are not plotted in the graph above, and are not included in calculating the mean.

Comment: This would seem to have a connection with repeated measures designs and with growth curves.